# Trying to make basic tabs

Tags: javascript, user-interface, tabs

Alright, so I have two buttons. My goal is to make the page so that when one button is clicked, it will display a paragraph, and when another is clicked it will close the other tab and display another paragraph. I thought this would be pretty simple, but getting one tab to close when the other is clicked has proved difficult.

```
function btn1Event(){
    var text1 = document.getElementById("btn1Text");
    var text2 = document.getElementById("btn2Text");

    if(text2.style.display == "inline" || text1.style.display == "none"){
        text1.style.display = "inline";
    }
}

function btn2Event(){
    var text1 = document.getElementById("btn1Text");
    var text2 = document.getElementById("btn2Text");

    if(text1.style.display == "inline" || text2.style.display == "none"){
        text2.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

Not exactly sure why this isn't working. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using jQuery if that is an option:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input type=button id="btn1" value="Show Div1">
<input type=button id="btn2" value="Show Div2">

<div style="display: none;" id="btn1Text">Test Div</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="btn2Text">Test Div2</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn1").click(function() {
            $("#btn1Text").show();
            $("#btn2Text").hide();
        });
        $("#btn2").click(function() {
            $("#btn1Text").hide();
            $("#btn2Text").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the non jQuery approach:

```
<input type=button id="btn1" value="Show Div1" onclick="btn1Event();">
<input type=button id="btn2" value="Show Div2" onclick="btn2Event();">

<div style="display: none;" id="btn1Text">Test Div</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="btn2Text">Test Div2</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function btn1Event(){
    document.getElementById("btn1Text").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("btn2Text").style.display = "none";
}

function btn2Event(){
    document.getElementById("btn1Text").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("btn2Text").style.display = "inline";
}

</script>
```

Comment: I can indeed use jQuery, however I generally don't like too, not because I have anything against it, but because I want to learn how to do things "from scratch", if you will.

Comment: ....And now I feel like an idiot. Thanks for answering my question, even if the answer was staring me in the face!

Comment: you are kidding right... the non-jquery code is identical to the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

All you are doing is setting the textbox display to inline. If you never set the display to none at any time, how do you expect any of the tabs to be hidden.

```
function btn1Event(){
    document.getElementById("btn1Text").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("btn2Text").style.display = "none";
}

function btn2Event(){
    document.getElementById("btn1Text").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("btn2Text").style.display = "inline";
}
```

Comment: This is a good point, but should probably have been a comment.

Comment: I set it to none in my CSS

Comment: Yes but once you toggle it to display inline once, it will be visible until you set the display back to none in javascript. So the tabs won't hide again once they've been shown once.

Comment: CSS only sets the initial display value. Once button1 is clicked the display for btn1text will be inline. Then when button2 is clicked btn2text will be inline, but unless you set btn1text display back to none, it won't be hidden at this point.